# What day is Nintendo's eShop updated on?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, wii-u

I've been looking around and can't seem to find any solid confirmation on what day new titles are added to the eShop.  I know within the next 7 days or so I'll find out, but I thought this might also make a good reference question for others.

So, to slightly rephrase; around the world, what day are new titles added to Nintendo's eShop for the 3DS and Wii U?

Comment: In rare instances the shop has been updated on non-Thursdays; Four Swords was released on a Wednesday. New shop categories and some videos seem to debut any time during the week.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the eShop will update on Thursdays, starting on June 16: [Nintendo moves US eShop updates to Thursdays](http://www.digitalspy.com/gaming/news/a324685/nintendo-moves-us-eshop-updates-to-thursdays.html).

Comment: The title implies that this is specific to the US eShop... or are they all updated on the same day?  I'm sure I remember the UK and US virtual console releases being different days on the Wii, not sure if the same still applies.  I guess we'll see tomorrow.

Comment: @Andy-E They will all be updating on the same day

Comment: Well, after today's pitiful update, I can at least mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @Andy the first big update came at the exact same time in the US and UK - however due to the time difference it was something like 2am on June 7 in the UK and 6pm June 6 in the US.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: thanks, I did think that we'd got the update a day later, but it makes sense that it was a simultaneous release.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2011/06/nintendo_download_16th_june_2011_north_america) article from Nintendo life states that the eShop, as well as all other Nintendo online stores will update on thursdays:

> Now the 3DS eShop is available, all
>   Nintendo's downloadable store fronts
>   will be updated on Thursdays. That
>   means WiiWare, DSiWare and 3DS
>   software will all go live on Thursday,
>   with press releases on the same day.